# json_prolog cpp client error?

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to call json_prolog cpp client, and get that error

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ros/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/bin$ ./object_positions
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'json_prolog::PrologQueryProxy::ServerNotFound'
  what():  No connection to the json_prolog server.
Aborted (core dumped)
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ros/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/bin$ roswtfLoaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Package: json_prolog
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * json_prolog: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rosjava_jni: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roslib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: connection refused to [http://amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:60818/]
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 4 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /fridge_handle

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /fridge_handle->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/fridge_handle/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/fridge_handle/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:41882]
 * service [/fridge_handle/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/fridge_handle/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:41882]
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54032/json_prolog-cpp-client-error-?!/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an error with your ROS setup, as the error messages tell you clearly: "No connection to the json_prolog server."

- Have you started the json_prolog service?
- Can you see the service with 'rosservice list'?
- You may need to set ROS_HOSTNAME or ROS_IP to your IP address

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1